# 'Access Denied' while loading PDF using AngularJS script in IE

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to load PDF as memory stream, which is got using web api, using Embed element. This works fine in Chrome but not in IE. I need this to be working in IE. Any clues please.

HTML:

```
<div id="pdfCont" style="height: 800px"/>
```

Here is the Javascript code I am using:

```
$http({method: 'GET', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, url: urlString, responseType : 'arraybuffer'})
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    var file = new Blob([data]);
    var fileURL = $scope.createObjectURL(file);
    var blobUrl = fileURL;                   
    $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
    var doc = $('<embed id=pdfDoc src="' + $scope.content + '" type="application/pdf" />');                    
    $('#pdfcont').empty().append(doc);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  });
```